# How to convert LGBM model from sklearn API to native API after training is completed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I have trained a lgbm model in sklearn API format just like this:

```
cb_classifier = LGBMClassifier(**params)


cb_classifier.fit(X_train[features],
                  y_train,
                  eval_set = (X_validation[features], y_validation),
                  categorical_feature = cat_dims
                  )
```

After the model was generated, I obtained the predictions for X_test with that model, but now I would like to obtain the same model for predicting the results in the native LGBM format, like:

```
native_lgbm_model.predict(X_test)
```

I tried saving the `cb_classifier` with booster like this:

```
cb_classifier.booster_.save_model("path/booster_lgbm.txt")

native_lgbm_model = lightgbm.Booster(model_file='path/booster_lgbm.txt')
```

But when trying to predict the results they were different from the results obtained when predicting with the sklearn API.

Is there any way to convert `cb_classifier` into native LGBM model?